# How to produce a more condensed document using ieeetran class?

Tags: spacing, ieeetran

I am revising a document based on the referee's comments. They wanted a list of things to add to a paper otherwise full of mathematical and textual material in just 14 pages using the `ieeetran` class.

Is there any method for making `ieeetran` produce a more condensed output? Are there any strategies for making a manuscript more condense while preserving the same material?

Comment: If you use the `IEEEtran` document class, it's presumably because the journal requires you to do so. You should not fiddle with the page size, font size, line spacing, and other parameters that affect how much material can be placed on a given page. The most you can do, really, is to check back with the journal's editorial staff and ask them if you're allowed to use either a different document class or a different page layout. Realistically, though, you should be concentrating your efforts on identifying all parts of the document that may be either shortened or omitted altogether.

Comment: If you really have to fit in significant amounts of new material you have no other option than removing or shortening some parts. Having said this, there are some dirty tricks of the trade that may work if the publisher/editor do not typeset the paper themselves but use your pdf version. Putting something like `\renewcommand\baselinestretch{0.98}` (the value has to be very close to 1) into the preamble may give you enough extra space while not changing the appearance too much.

Comment: @gernot If I were the typesetter of the journal, you would likely get the paper rejected or sent back for correction because of this. That's not a good advice, and if you really insist on fiddling with LaTeX in a journal paper, there are better ways.

Comment: @yo' Journals have higher typesetting standards, but usually don't have page limits; I never had problems there. But conferences have page limits and tight time limits. There it may happen that the trade-off between typesetting requirements and sleeping time of the author may let appear such dirty tricks less abominable.

Comment: @gernot Don't be mistaken, many journals _do_ have strict page restrictions.

Comment: (reposting my comment as it was auto-deleted) You should not fiddle with the LaTeX side of the document. The problem you describe is entirely between you, the reviewer and the editor, not between you and LaTeX. So you better ask the folks at [Academia.SE].SE on how to deal with the situation.